# google.script.run.withSuccessHandler works for me but not other users

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, onclick, prompt

The following `OnClick` closes a DialogBox and its `withSuccessHandler` opens a UI.Prompt.
This successfully closes the Starting UI for me but no other user. Why is this?

```
onClick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(){google.script.host.close();}).someOtherFunction()
```

Did I miss something about sharing my Excel App Scripts with other users?

Full Code here:

```
function onOpen() {
   var menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("⚙️ Start App");
   menu.addItem("Start", "StartPopup");  
   menu.addToUi();
}

async function StartPopup(){

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  
  var html = `
    <p>  App Modes </p> </center>
    <p class="body" style="font-family: sans-serif; color:gray; text-align:left">
    Options:</p>

    <body>

    <p>
    <input type="button" id="no" value="RUN" onClick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(){google.script.host.close();}).userPromptcustomFunction()"/>
    </p>
      </body>  ` 
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService
      .createHtmlOutput(html)
      .setWidth(700)
      .setHeight(600);


  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'My Excel App.');


}

function userPromptcustomFunction(){
  currentMonth = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt("Choose Month to Perform Operation.", ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
}
```

Comment: `...host.close()`. Note `()`

Comment: I think that's the issue. Update your code in the editor. Create a new version and Deploy it  and share it to your  users and see if the issue is reproducible.

Comment: @TheMaster, this is a bound script.  `SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog()` can only be used from a spreadsheet context.  So I don't quite understand your answer.  I think it would be better to simply have an <input> tag with a text field in the html dialog.  Then google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(close).userPromptcustomFunction(month)`.  Either use the month immediately or store it in PropertyService for later use.

Comment: Still an error with close()

Comment: Placing the month doesn't help close app.script.host.close() - still an error @TheWizEd

Comment: The other user might have be using multiple account sign-in and the spreadsheet is not shared with the default account of the user. This is a know issue. If you need further help please add more details, like the logs messages, if this happens also to other users when using Chrome in incognito mode with all the extensions disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead.  I get the user input from the modal dialog and then send to the server.

[image]

```
function StartPopup(){
  try {
    var html = `
    <body>
      <p>  App Modes </p> </center>
      <p class="body" style="font-family: sans-serif; color:gray; text-align:left">
        Options:
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="month">Choose Month to Perform Operation</label>
        <input type="text" id="month">
      </p>
      <p>
        <input type="button" id="no" value="RUN" onClick="buttonOnClick()"/>
      </p>
      <script>
        function buttonOnClick() {
          let month = document.getElementById("month").value;
          alert(month);
          google.script.run.withSuccessHandler( function () { google.script.host.close(); }).userPromptcustomFunction(month);
        }
      </script>
    </body>  `
    var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput,"My Google App Script");
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
  }
}

function userPromptcustomFunction(month) {
  try {
    let prop = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
    prop.setProperty("month",month);
    Logger.log("montn = "+prop.getProperty("month"));
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
  }
}
```

Execution log

```
Head    userPromptcustomFunction    Unknown Oct 11, 2022, 9:03:47 AM    1.426 s 
Completed
Cloud logs
Oct 11, 2022, 9:03:49 AM    Info    montn = Jan
```

Comment: So it works now with both users, and after replicating this I realize the key point seems to be that <script>... Thanks for your help